How to configure Spring Security using SecurityFilterChain to enable login with JWT and Aauth2Login together in the same application?
I'm trying to implement two security systems in the same application: one using JWT at /auth/login and another with OAuth2 (I want to use GitHub and Google for authentication) at /auth/auth2.
I couldn't make them work together; I can use each one separately but not together. It applies JWT or OAuth2 login, but not both together.
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExceptionHandlingConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    
    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler JWTAccesDeniedHandler;

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authManager(HttpSecurity http,
                                             PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
                                             UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {
        
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        
        authBuilder
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService) 
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder); 
            
        return authBuilder.build();

    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
          .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
          .authorizeHttpRequests (rq -> {
            rq.requestMatchers("/auth/login/**").permitAll();
            rq.requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll();
            rq.requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**").permitAll();
            rq.anyRequest().authenticated();
            }   
          )
          .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
          .exceptionHandling(configureExceptionHandling())
          .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .build();
    }

    private Customizer<ExceptionHandlingConfigurer<HttpSecurity>> configureExceptionHandling() {
    
        return configureExceptionHandling -> {
            configureExceptionHandling.accessDeniedHandler(JWTAccesDeniedHandler);
            configureExceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);
        };
    }
}

I have tried many solutions, such as declaring multiple beans for SecurityFilterChain, setting different priorities for the beans. I have tried many combinations and customizations, changing the order and URLs too.
